# Proof of Hahn-Banach theorem from Compactness theorem of FOL

Tags: functional-analysis, logic, first-order-logic, alternative-proof, hahn-banach-theorem

Since the Compactness theorem of FOL is equivalent to the ultrafilter Lemma, which implies Hahn-Banach, the implication is clear to me. I was more just wondering if there is a nice direct proof? I saw in another thread that Compactness very nicely proves the existence and uniqueness of Algebraic closures, so I thought maybe there's a neat proof of Hahn-Banach as well. I just can't think of a good way to axiomatize the statement, as the class of topological spaces and normed spaces is not axiomatizable, and I'm guessing the class of locally convex topological vector-spaces is neither using similar arguments. Can anyone help out?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The compactness theorem for propositional calculus is very natually equivalent to the statement that $2^X$ is compact in the product topology for any set $X$.  The proof of Hahn-Banach uses the fact that $I^X$ is compact in the product topology where $I=[0,1]$.  The obstacle is the move from $2^X$ to $I^X$ because it leaves the realm of the discrete to something using $\Bbb{R}$.  The proof that the UL implies $I^X$ is compact is similar to the proof of the Tychonoff theorem, except that $I$ being Hausdorff makes using the full AC unnecessary.

Comment: Addendum: If $C=2^{\omega}$ is the Cantor set, then $2^X$ being compact for all $X$ implies that $C^X\equiv 2^{\omega \times X}$ is compact.  $C$ is not homeomorphic to $I$, but there is a continuous surjection $C\twoheadrightarrow I$, so it may be possible to prove that $I^X$ is compact from $C^X$ is compact.

Comment: @ChadK first of all, clever little argument in your second comment. Secondly, I was more thinking of a direct proof, using some axiomatization and then arguing as finite dimensional extensions of a linear functional are always possible (have some form of model), so is an arbitrary extension using compactness. While your proof most certainly works, it goes more along the lines of taking an excursion around Ultrafilters or Tychonoff (for Hausdorff spaces), which I wanted to avoid. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough in the post.

Comment: How about this - axiomatize a vector space over a real-closed field in first-order logic.  Add function symbols for the linear functional $f$ and sub-linear function $p$ from the Hahn-Banach theorem.  Add the axioms that $f$ is linear and $p$ is sub-linear.  Add a constant to represent each vector in the vector space.  For each constant add as axiom the equation that $f$ is bounded by $p$ for this constant . Now prove that for any finite subset of axioms there is a model by satisfying the equations for finitely many constants.  Use compactness to deduce a model the entire set of equations.